# Mysql change values to insert on duplicate key

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to do it? Considering I have the following table:

```
 id | value
----|------
 1  | A
 2  | B
```

If I try to insert the values `(1, "C")` I get `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'` as expected, considering `id` is a unique primary key. So, I tried using the following insert inside an `AFTER INSERT ON` trigger with the following insert syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.value)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NEW.id = NEW.id + 5000;
```

It removes the duplicate key error, but it just won't insert the duplicate one(s).

I made a procedure following Yogi's suggestion. This is what it looks like:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE set_keys(IN id INT, IN value char(1))
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062
    SELECT concat('Duplicate keys detected: ',id,', ',value) AS msg;

    INSERT INTO tests (id, value) VALUES(id + 5000, value);
END;
//
```

Is doing `CALL set_keys(NEW.id, NEW.value);` from now on the proper way to do it?

Comment: isn't simpler to use an auto-increment key? P.s. consider that using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE you don't insert the new row, simply edit the old one, so you 1-A becomes 5001-A and 1-C is lost

Comment: @RobertoBisello It would, but I'm importing data from another database, and can't modify the original one except for inserts. If the other database gives me 1-C, I should be able to insert it and keep both values from the column `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than directly performing **INSERT** INTO table,
You can perform this using **PROCEDURE/FUNCTION**.

Do exception handling for **DUPLICATE KEY** error under **EXCEPTION** block, increment the KEY column and RE_RUN the **INSERT** Statement again

Comment: Would making a function that does somethink like `select count(*) from table where id = @id_to_insert` and make an "if count = 1, add 5000" work? I'm sorry, I just don't know *that* much about mysql :/

Comment: @Newwt -- Only problem i see with your answer is, before every insert i will run one extra query, where as with exception handling, i will run extra query for duplicate records only...

Comment: I informed myself a little and -I think- I did what you suggested. Do you mind checking my edit on the question to see if I did it right? Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @Newwt- Yes, Seems Correct to me. You need CONTINUE HANDLER, which you are using

Comment: I noticed just now if for example I try to insert an id of 1 without anything on the table, it inserts it directly as `id + 5000`, without there being a duplicate. What is causing it?